# Remove the data stored in ReplySubject Object on LogOut function. in Android RxJava/Android

Tags: android, session, rx-java, observable, rx-android

Am facing an issue am using RxJava/Android in my application.
And Am Calling API using `Observable<>` and storing data with `ReplaySubject`. But now the problem is when I **log out** from the app the previously stored data stay still there. It meant to be clear after user logout from the session, but the newly logged in user is seeing old data rather than his new data, So how can I achieve clearing that data after logout?

**Calling API here:**

```
io.reactivex.Observable<Users> observableusers = apiClient.getUser(headers);
        observableusers.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(CommonSubjects.UsersSubject);
      CommonSubjects.UsersSubject.subscribe(new Observer<Users>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Users users) {
            if (users.getUsers().get(0).getSize() == 0) {
                message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                shimmerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                usersList.addAll(users.getRatings());
                usersList.remove(0);
                usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(R.layout.layout_user_review, userList, context,recyclerView);
                shimmerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            CommonSubjects.FeedsSubject.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io());//This is try am doing
        }
    });
```

I have commented in OnComplete about how am trying to do it.

**Storing Data using ReplaySubject**

```
public static ReplaySubject<User> UserSubject = ReplaySubject.create();
```

Any Help on this is welcome.

Comment: How many users can be there? Perhaps [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) could work for you.

Comment: It is big no. of users and their information. @akarnokd